# Dynamical Evaluation error and infinite loop?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, physics

I'm trying to set up a solver to solve for the chemical potential 
given the constraints (particle number and magnetization). 
The function `MuandShift` finds the value of chemical potential,
`mu`,and shift parameter `shift` that conserve the number of 
electrons while yielding the magnetisation that is given by equation `M[T]`.

```
M[T_] := Msat0 (1 - Tanh[alpha (T - Tc)]) (1 - beta (T/Tc))^(3/2)

MuandShift0[T_] := FindRoot[{TotalParticles0[mu, shift, T] - NumberofElectrons0, Magnetisation0[mu, shift, T] - M[T]}, {{mu, .001}, {shift, 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 1]
MuandShiftP0[T_] := FindRoot[{TotalParticles0[mu, shift, T] - NumberofElectrons0, Magnetisation0[mu, shift, T] - nlm[T]}, {{mu, .001}, {shift, 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

and the other relevant functions being:

```
TotalParticles0[mu_, shift_?NumericQ, T_] := NIntegrate[EnergyUpSpin0[(En - shift)]*Fermi[En, mu, T], {En,ListLaFeSiDWN0[[1]][[1]] + shift, 5 + shift}, MinRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 7, MaxRecursion -> 40, PrecisionGoal -> 2] + NIntegrate[-EnergyDownSpin0[(En + shift)]*Fermi[En, mu, T], {En,ListLaFeSiDWN0[[1]][[1]] - shift, 5 - shift}, MinRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 7, MaxRecursion -> 40, PrecisionGoal -> 2]

Magnetisation0[mu_, shift_?NumericQ, T_] := NIntegrate[EnergyUpSpin0[(En - shift)]*Fermi[En, mu, T], {En, ListLaFeSiDWN0[[1]][[1]] shift, 5 + shift}, MinRecursion -> 20 , WorkingPrecision -> 9, MaxRecursion -> 40, PrecisionGoal -> 2] + NIntegrate[+EnergyDownSpin0[(En + shift)]*Fermi[En, mu, T], {En, ListLaFeSiDWN0[[1]][[1]] - shift, 5 - shift}, MinRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 9, MaxRecursion -> 40, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

Where `NumberofElectrons0` = `TotalParticles0[0, 0, 0]` and similarly for the magnetization. All the other relevant functions are interpolations of data. The problem is when when I run the code, and try to solve for `MuandShift0[120]`, it gives me the following error:

> Integrate::nlim: "En = -17.74110+shift is not a valid limit of
>   integration"

The solver never completed - after the above errors, I once again got the

> "kernel is not responding to a dynamic evaluation"

I don't know what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: This suggests that the variable `shift` isn't being numerically defined. How exactly are do you define `shift`?

Comment: @Feyre shift is being defined like any other variable. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: You're using `NIntegrate`, so all the variables and the domain must be numeric, however the error message suggests `shift` isn't numeric.

Comment: @Feyre well MuandShift0 returns two variable, Mu and shift, that solve the system of equations define in terms of Nintegrate. So, they should both be numbers...I haven't done anything to specify otherwise.

Comment: Please? Any help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP wanted his code debugged, but unfortunately did not provide enough info to do so, even when prodded in comments.